# How to configure MQTT-SN Security setting in RSMB?

Tags: security, mqtt

I've build a MQTT-SN RSMB on my raspberry pi.

And I want to add same Security setting in RSMB.

After reading "Getting started with the Really Small Message Broker",I add two configurations in broker.cfg

[image]

But it seems unrecognized and has some error messages,so that it can't workout with security configurations, I wonder to know how to setting security configurations correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

When I changed the configurations from bottom to the top, It works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVIpg.png)